# How can we get the turnabout time for any Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to find out what is the actual time taken by my ES cluster to return the query result to the client. 
I understand from googling and reading that **took** time which we get in ES response can't be taken as the correct measure. Is there any other way or logs which I can enable , because if I enable the slow logs it also gives to took time. 
The reason why I am looking for this is while querying ES from my client I am seeing took time and the time by which I get the response is huge. And I am unable to trace/pinpoint the reason, is it because of lag in between servers or ES is consuming more time to send the response.

Comment: I would leverage [Elastic APM distributed tracing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/distributed-tracing.html)

Comment: @Val unfortunately I am stuck with ES 5.4.0, anything for that???